# Why is my alias not working in Zsh?

Tags: command-line, alias, zsh

I have added my alias to `~/.aliases` file and the file right now is like this:

```
alias gss="git status"
alias gl="git log"
alias pa="php artisan"
alias reload=". ~/.zshrc && echo 'ZSH config reloaded from ~/.zshrc'"
```

When I run `gss`, `gl`, `reload` they all work, but when I run `pa` I am getting an error `zsh: command not found: pa` why is that?

Comment: Have you sourced the file ? Try this `source ~/.aliases` and then run commands.

Comment: i found my problem i wrote it as an answer so someone in need like me  can read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I was editing the wrong file.

I edited my `~/.zshrc` file to add the aliases. Everything works fine after that.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you can keep your aliases in `~/.aliases` file itself which can be portable across systems but then add below lines at the end of `~/.zshrc` to include all of them

```
#...more zsh config above

if [ -f ~/.aliases ]; then
        . ~/.aliases
fi
```

Comment: right approach.